# New cell with range between two cells

Tags: formula, openoffice-calc

I have a cell with vehicle model years (starting A:2 and ending B:2) for example A:2 is 1997 and B:2 is 2001 How can I make the single cell C:2 show the range of years for example 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 I need this for a shopping cart that will query specific years. My files have about 15,000 rows so I need to do this with a formula.

I need the end result to go into either the single cell c:2 or to populate in single cells to the right example c;2 d;2 e;2 etc. It is preferred to have them in a single cell separated by a space not a comma as this will be uploaded as a .csv file.

Comment: OP is a greenhorn at calc and has no idea what to try after hours of searching.

Answer (score 0):

In **C2** enter:

=A2

In **C3** enter:

```
=IF( MAX($C$1:C2)=$B$2,"",C2+1)
```

and copy down

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

In order to place the result into a **single cell** run the following macro rather than using formulas:

```
Sub SpanOfYears()
    Dim FirstCell As Range, SecondCell As Range, Result As Range
    Dim I As Long

    Set FirstCell = Range("A2")
    Set SecondCell = Range("B2")
    Set Result = Range("C2")

    For I = FirstCell.Value To SecondCell.Value
        Result.Value = Result.Value & " " & I
    Next I
End Sub
```

with this result:

[image]

**EDIT#2**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: That looks great however can this be done in a single cell or row? The program I use to upload the file to the cart interprets each row as a singe record. Thanks.

Comment: @user1020339  **yes**  update your question to show the details of the input.

Comment: Thank you @Gary's Student. That looks exactly like what I need. Now i just have to read up on using macros and I should be good to go.